# How to download the Sentinel-3 OLCI WFR data

Tags: data, sentinel-3

I am interested in Sentinel-3 data concerning water parameters: [OLCI WFR at level 2](https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-3-olci/product-types/level-2-water).

I've never used Sentinel data before so probably I am just doing something wrong. Based on the *Sentinel User Guide* I assumed that since I want to use Level 2 product I just need to set L2 product level in Mission Sentinel-3 and choose OLCI instrument. Then I should just choose the appropriate product type: OL2_WFR_. However no such product is available nor in search  field nor in the products returned by the serach without specification of that field. How can I get this data?

[image: Search entries]

The available product types

[image: Product types]

Comment: If this is open data then I think the place to ask questions about accessing it is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score -1):

I think those products are produced by EUMETSAT. [This page](https://navigator.eumetsat.int/product/EO:EUM:DAT:SENTINEL-3:OL_2_WFR___NTC?query=OLCI%20Level%202%20Ocean%20Colour%20Full%20Resolution%20in%20NTC%20-%20Sentinel-3&s=advanced) has links to the data (see [eg](https://data.eumetsat.int/data/map/EO:EUM:DAT:0407?facets=timeliness%7CNT&page=0,20&sort=start,time,0&displayProduct=S3B_OL_2_WFR____20221019T030201_20221019T030501_20221020T144714_0179_071_360_2880_MAR_O_NT_003.SEN3) for example)